# fetching values returned from SOQL query into map but map's id shouldn't be Id of soql

Tags: soql, map

For example... I have a SOQL query :-

```
[SELECT name, profile.name, email, isActive 
 from User 
 where UserRoleId in 
      (SELECT ID from UserRole WHERE name in ('CEO','COO','ALC Midwest','ALC Southwest'))
];
```

Now each role may have more than one users.

So, My requirement is that I want a map with key = UserRoleID and value = list of all users under that role.

So is it possible to do this without looping the above query's result and then putting values into map

Or some GROUP BY clause (or something else) can help me do this efficiently..

If nothing is possible and only looping is the only way then please provide an efficient and optimized code than the normal one-by-one row looping.

Help me its urgent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this map:

```
Map<Id, UserRole> m = new Map<Id, UserRole>([
        select Id, (select UserName, ProfileId from Users order by UserName)
        from UserRole
        ]);
```

and then the list of users would be:

```
Id userRoleId = ...;
User[] users = m.get(userRoleId).Users;
```

Comment: SOQL query always return `Map<Id, ObjectName>` so if we can assign soql query to such map so unnecessary "for-loop" can be avoid.